# Is it safe to amend old pushed commit message?

Tags: git, git-amend

I was following [this](http://schacon.github.com/history.html) document to amend an already pushed commit message. I now have my local branch containing the amended message, and copies of all the commits following the amended one.

I know for sure that other people have already pulled those commits.

Is it safe to push my local branch? What will be the consequences for others?

Comment: Well the message in this document is pretty clear:  `Do not include any commit you have already pushed to a central server - it will mess other people up.` isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you amended *any* commit then it means that you have rewritten the history of that branch.  Note that just changing the commit message means that Git created a *new* commit in place of the old one.  I don't know whether you used an interactive rebase, filter branch, or `git commit --amend`, but it won't change the situation much.

The consequences of pushing this branch are that everyone else using this branch may get a merge commit when trying to pull.  The reason for this can be seen in the following diagram:

```
remote: A -- B -- C -- E       # you rewrote D to C
local:  A -- B -- D -- E
```

When one of your colleagues attempts to pull, Git will find the `B` commit as being the common ancestor between the local and remote branch.  It will first try to fast forward the local branch with `C -- E`, but then realize that this is also not possible, because the local branch has diverged and has its own set of commits on top of `B`.  As a result, Git will end up creating a merge commit with the changes from the remote.  But this will include both commits `C` and `D`, which could lead to weirdness.

The only exception to this happening would be someone who has not pulled the branch since commit `B` or earlier.  In this case, such a person would not notice that you rewrote that commit, because his local history would have had no knowledge of this commit in the first place.

Note if you wish to proceed, your colleagues might want to do this:

```
git fetch origin                 # update tracking branches
git reset --hard origin/master   # reset local master to remote (effectively overwrite)
```

Comment: So.. it is too late to fix the message. I can live with that.

Comment: @Elist You certainly can change the message, but you need to let your team know.  If you have a tight enough conspiracy, you can rewrite history and get away with it.  But in general, you should avoid rewriting the history of publicly shared branches.

Comment: I actually don't really get it - why can't git facilitate seamless amendments to messages, which will keep the history and only change the message? Such changes can do no harm and hence can be considered fast-forward, and could be applied once you fetch the repository.

Comment: A Git commit is treated as a record of what actually happened.  Changing the commit message could be construed to be a type of forgery.  Imagine a hedge fund or high frequency trading firm, which lost a bunch of money due to bad code.  Now imagine if the engineers could just go back and remove some incriminating commit messages.  This and other reasons is why Git requires making a new commit.

Comment: That is completely right for the commit contents. I would think the message can be considered less important.. But again, I can live with that.